# How do I authorize Tweepy to post on Twitter?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to make a Twitter post, but I keep getting `tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized`. So I decided to use `api.verify_credentials()` to check if I'm able to connect and voila: `Authentication Successful`. But even so, the post is still not authorized.

How do I authorize Tweepy to post to Twitter?

```py
import tweepy


def main():
    consumer_key = '...'
    consumer_secret = '...'
    access_token = '...'
    access_token_secret = '...'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
        print("Authentication Successful")
    except:
        print("Authentication Error")

    status = "Another day, another cup of #coffee"

    api.update_status(status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what I am getting:

```sh
Authentication Successful
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arnon/Downloads/mail_read/post_tweet.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/arnon/Downloads/mail_read/post_tweet.py", line 30, in main
    api.update_status(status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1121, in update_status
    return self.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 257, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this in Twitter Community:

> When creating your application, do not click the “create your access token” until you first click on Settings and change the Application Type to “Read, Write and Access direct messages”.
> After your Twitter application has been updated to “Read, Write and Access direct messages”, click on the Home tab, and “create your access token”.
> This should do the trick =)

Source: https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-401-unauthorized/367/13

Comment: This is correct for sure and easy to miss. After this has been done, the examples tells it like it is, really straight forward : https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/API_v2/create_tweet.py

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and that's how I managed to fix it:
the problem is probably that your access tokens do not have the needed permissions.

**STEP BY STEP SOLUTION**

1. Go to https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/projects-and-apps
2. Go to Keys and tokens tab of the app that you want
   [image]
3. Check the permissions of your app checking what it writes below of the "Access Token and Secret"
   [image]
4. If it has only the Read permission go to the Settings tab of your app
5. Click to Set Up the user authentication settings
   [image]
6. Enable the "OAuth 1.0a" and change the app permission to "Read and write and Direct message"
   [image]
7. Regenerate the tokens

Comment: This solution helped me. Crazy, after almost inventing hot water :D

Comment: @nick-pantelidis Hello I can't go to that url now. I already had a app before. It is redireting me to https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/petition/essential/basic-info?plan=pro,? and even if I fill the data it just says something went wrong. Bogus. How to solve this

Comment: Just go to the developer portal (https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard) and check the status of your project and app. There were some changes in the Twitter API recently. So you have maybe to change the access level of your project from the Essential level (that it was the old one) to the Free level.

Answer (score 1):

Check the keys and tokens, make sure they are correct. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401,
The HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

This might also help:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-1a-authentication