# How to Create Tweet with OAuth 2.0 (Twitter API v2) using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I try to create a tweet using tweepy under OAuth 2.0 instead of OAuth 1.0a. In other words, I am looking for an OAuth 2.0 equivalent of the following code.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)
response = client.create_tweet(
    text="This Tweet was Tweeted using Tweepy and Twitter API v2!"
)
print(f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{response.data['id']}")
```

Following Twitter's guide on [OAuth 2.0 Making requests on behalf of users](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token) and tweepy's guide on [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (User Context)](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#oauth-2-0-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce-user-context), I am able to obtain an access token, which is passed instead of the Bearer Token.

```
import tweepy

client_id = ""
redirect_uri = ""
client_secret = ""

oauth2_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth2UserHandler(
    client_id=client_id,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope=["tweet.read", "tweet.write", "users.read"],
    client_secret=client_secret
)

print(oauth2_user_handler.get_authorization_url())

authorization_response = input("--> ")

access_token = oauth2_user_handler.fetch_token(
    authorization_response
)


client = tweepy.Client(access_token)
```

It seems that [Twitter's implementation of OAuth 2.0 is in unfinished](https://twittercommunity.com/t/which-api-to-get-user-after-oauth2-authorization/162417) as of Dec '21. However, in Feb '21, [the steps to post Tweets on behalf of users under OAuth 2.0](https://forum.bubble.io/t/login-with-twitter-and-post-tweet-on-behalf-of-user/74418/13) was described in another forum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482492/twitter-new-api-essential-access/70650265#70650265 might help? or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69429618/how-do-i-authorize-tweepy-to-post-on-twitter/69429654#69429654

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewRyan. The second link uses OAuth 1.0a. The first link is an early stage of the problem, where the OP first encountered not being able to create tweet (read-only). If the OP choose to use OAuth 1.0a, they can use the solution from the second link. If the OP choose to use OAuth 2.0, they may run into the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is found.

```
client = tweepy.Client(access_token["access_token"])


response = client.create_tweet(
    text="This Tweet was Tweeted using Tweepy and Twitter API v2!",
    user_auth=False
)
print(f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{response.data['id']}")
```

Comment: What is (access_token["access_token"]) ?